# Flush my sharedObject in as3 - delete all states and start from the beginning

Tags: actionscript-3, flush, shared-objects, local-shared-object

I was hoping someone could help. I would assume this to be a straight forward thing to do yet seem to be struggling with it a bit. I'm novice to using sharedObjects although it's becoming a bit more familiar to me.

I'm wanting to wipe **all sharedObject data** at the touch of a button... that's all. The trace is showing up but there is no activity.

```
reset_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startover);

function startover(event:MouseEvent):void
{
 //gotoAndPlay(2);
    //reset_balloon.visible = true;
    mySO = SharedObject.getLocal("iDesign");
    delete mySO.data.my_y; 
    //delete mySO.data.mybut_x;
    //delete mySO.data.mybut_y;
    delete mySO.data.mytig_x;
    delete mySO.data.mytig_y;   
    delete mySO.data.mybow_x;
    delete mySO.data.mybow_y;
    delete mySO.data.myblkbow_y;
    delete mySO.data.myblkbow_x;
    delete mySO.data.mybut_x;
    delete mySO.data.mybut_y;
    mySO.flush();
    trace("deleteinside");
}
```

Any clues?

UPDATES TO CODE -------------------------------

```
reset_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startover);

function startover(event:MouseEvent):void
  {
    mySO = SharedObject.getLocal("iDesign");
    //delete mySO.data.my_y; 
    //delete mySO.data.mybut_x;
    //delete mySO.data.mybut_y;
    //delete mySO.data.mytig_x;
    //delete mySO.data.mytig_y; 
    //delete mySO.data.mybow_x;
    //delete mySO.data.mybow_y;
    //delete mySO.data.myblkbow_y;
    //delete mySO.data.myblkbow_x;
    //delete mySO.data.mybut_x;
    //delete mySO.data.mybut_y;
    mySO.flush();
    trace("deleteinside");
    mySO.clear();
}
```

Ignore all of the deletes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to wipe all `SharedObject` data is to call [`mySO.clear()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html#clear%28%29).

Comment: Hello thanks, although nothing appears to happen when I attach the script to the button click. mySO.clear(); will I need to attach the script to each piece of data?

Comment: You should only have to call `mySO.clear()` once. You can try following it up with a `mySO.flush()` for good measure, but in my testing, `clear` wipes the entire data object.

Comment: Please post the latest version of your code so we can see where it may be failing.

Comment: Morning! for some strange reason the script appears to be working! Code added above.

Comment: Not that it matters much (since it's working), but you probably don't need to call `flush` before you call `clear`.